# Вывод массива с определенного номера

Tags: php

К примеру, есть массив из 10 ячеек. И нужно вывести, начиная с 5, и чтобы вывод поулчался такой:

```
5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4
```

Нужно все равно, чтобы выводился весь массив, но начиная с какого-либо.

Comment: Уточните язык.

Comment: php
Но мне бы теорию хотя бы

Comment: Нужно узнать, как выводить массивы?

Answer (score 2):

```
$start = 5;
$a = array(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19);
$max_i = count($a);
for ($i = 0; $i < $max_i; $i++) {
    $n = ($start + $i) % $max_i;
    echo "a[$n]=", $a[$n], "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**

```
$count=count($your_mass);
$from=5;
for ($i=$from;$i<=$count;$i++;)
    echo "№".$i." элемент=".$your_mass[$i]."<br />";
for ($i=0;$i<=$from;$i++;)
    echo "№".$i." элемент=".$your_mass[$i]."<br />";
```

**

Ну если по глупому то можно так

Но если подумать логически можно сделать в одном цикле.

Comment: Ну да, по глупому=), хотя спасибо, что время уделили

Comment: хех :) работы много.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$start = 5;

foreach (array_merge(array_slice($array, $start), array_slice($array, 0, $start)) as $i) {
    echo "$i\n";
}
```

Comment: Вот это больше всего нравится!) Спасибо